# Kotlin Multiplatform: iOS packForXcode: linkDebugFrameworkIos : Compilation failed: No coordinates found for DeclarationId(id=4)

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I migrated existing project to kotlin-native, Android app build but iOS `packForXcode` task throw exception:

build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinTargetContainerWithPresetFunctions
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.3.72"
    id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
}

repositories {
    // artifacts are published to JCenter
    jcenter()
    maven("https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx")
}

version = "1.0"

android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(21)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

kotlin {
    // CocoaPods requires the podspec to have a version.
    val name = "Shared"

    val iOSTarget: (String, KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> KotlinNativeTarget =
            if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
                ::iosArm64
            else
                ::iosX64

    iOSTarget("ios") {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = name
            }
        }
    }

    android()

    val ktorVersion = "1.3.2"
    val coroutinesVersion = "1.3.8"
    val serializationVersion = "0.20.0"
    val kotlinVersion = "1.3.72"
    val sqldelightVersion = "1.4.0"
    val kodeinVersion = "6.5.5"
    val reaktiveVersion = "1.1.16"

    sourceSets {

        sourceSets {
            all {
                dependencies {
                    implementation ("org.kodein.di:kodein-di-core:$kodeinVersion")
                    implementation ("org.kodein.di:kodein-di-erased:$kodeinVersion")
                }
            }

            commonMain {
                dependencies {
                    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common")
                    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlinVersion")
                    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:$coroutinesVersion")
                    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:$serializationVersion")
                    //KTOR
                    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktorVersion")
                    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktorVersion")
                    //DB
                    implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:$sqldelightVersion")
                    implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:coroutines-extensions:$sqldelightVersion")
                    //RX
                    implementation ("com.badoo.reaktive:reaktive:$reaktiveVersion")
                    implementation ("com.badoo.reaktive:reaktive-annotations:$reaktiveVersion")
                    implementation ("com.badoo.reaktive:coroutines-interop:$reaktiveVersion")
                }
            }

            commonTest {
                dependencies {
                    implementation ("com.badoo.reaktive:reaktive-testing:$reaktiveVersion")
                }
            }

            android {
                dependencies {
                    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")
                    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutinesVersion")
                    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:$serializationVersion")
                    //VM
                    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0")
                    //KTOR
                    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktorVersion")
                    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-jvm:$ktorVersion")
                    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-jvm:$ktorVersion")
                    //DB
                    implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:$sqldelightVersion")
                }
            }

        }

        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:$coroutinesVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:$serializationVersion")
                //KTOR
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-native:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-native:$ktorVersion")
                //DB
                implementation ("com.squareup.sqldelight:native-driver:$sqldelightVersion")
            }
        }
    }

}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")

    /// selecting the right configuration for the iOS
    /// framework depending on the environment
    /// variables set by Xcode build
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val framework = kotlin.targets
            .getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>("ios")
            .binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)

    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)

    /// generate a helpful ./gradlew wrapper with embedded Java path
    doLast {
        val gradlew = File(targetDir, "gradlew")
        gradlew.writeText(
                "#!/bin/bash\n"
                        + "export 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\n"
                        + "cd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n"
                        + "./gradlew \$@\n"
        )
        gradlew.setExecutable(true)
    }
}

tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)

tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

sqldelight {
    database("Database") {
        packageName = "com.db"
    }
    linkSqlite = false
}
```

Exception:

```
> Task :module:linkDebugFrameworkIos FAILED
e: Compilation failed: No coordinates found for DeclarationId(id=4)

 * Source files: 
 * Compiler version info: Konan: 1.3.72 / Kotlin: 1.3.72
 * Output kind: FRAMEWORK

e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No coordinates found for DeclarationId(id=4)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.library.impl.IrMultiTableReader.tableItemBytes(IrFileReaders.kt:134)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.library.impl.IrMonoliticLibraryImpl.loadIrDeclaration(KotlinLibraryImpl.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.library.impl.IrMonoliticLibraryImpl.irDeclaration(KotlinLibraryImpl.kt:87)
e: Compilation failed: No coordinates found for DeclarationId(id=4)

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.konan.library.impl.KonanLibraryImpl.irDeclaration(KonanLibraryImpl.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.serialization.KonanIrLinker.reader-IJqt95E(KonanIrlinker.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.KotlinIrLinker$IrModuleDeserializer$IrDeserializerForFile.loadTopLevelDeclarationProto-Yzffb84(KotlinIrLinker.kt:183)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.KotlinIrLinker$IrModuleDeserializer$IrDeserializerForFile.deserializeDeclaration-Yzffb84(KotlinIrLinker.kt:164)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.KotlinIrLinker$IrModuleDeserializer$IrDeserializerForFile$deserializeAllFileReachableTopLevel$1.invoke(KotlinIrLinker.kt:417)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.KotlinIrLinker$IrModuleDeserializer$IrDeserializerForFile$deserializeAllFileReachableTopLevel$1.invoke(KotlinIrLinker.kt:142)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.KotlinIrLinker$DeserializationState$SimpleDeserializationState.processPendingDeclarations(KotlinIrLinker.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.KotlinIrLinker$IrModuleDeserializer$IrDeserializerForFile.deserializeAllFileReachableTopLevel(KotlinIrLinker.kt:416)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.KotlinIrLinker$IrModuleDeserializer$deserializeAllModuleReachableTopLevels$1.invoke(KotlinIrLinker.kt:483)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.KotlinIrLinker$IrModuleDeserializer$deserializeAllModuleReachableTopLevels$1.invoke(KotlinIrLinker.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.KotlinIrLinker$DeserializationState$ModuleDeserializationState.processPendingDeclarations(KotlinIrLinker.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.KotlinIrLinker$IrModuleDeserializer.deserializeAllModuleReachableTopLevels(KotlinIrLinker.kt:481)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.KotlinIrLinker.deserializeAllReachableTopLevels(KotlinIrLinker.kt:543)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.KotlinIrLinker.findDeserializedDeclarationForDescriptor(KotlinIrLinker.kt:574)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.KotlinIrLinker.getDeclaration(KotlinIrLinker.kt:581)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.ExternalDependenciesGeneratorKt.getDeclaration(ExternalDependenciesGenerator.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.ExternalDependenciesGenerator.generateUnboundSymbolsAsDependencies(ExternalDependenciesGenerator.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ModuleGenerator.generateUnboundSymbolsAsDependencies(ModuleGenerator.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.ToplevelPhasesKt$psiToIrPhase$1.invoke(ToplevelPhases.kt:215)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.ToplevelPhasesKt$psiToIrPhase$1.invoke(ToplevelPhases.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PhaseBuildersKt$namedOpUnitPhase$1.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:149)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PhaseBuildersKt$namedOpUnitPhase$1.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:147)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper$runBody$1.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:128)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.downlevel(CompilerPhase.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper.runBody(CompilerPhase.kt:127)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:30)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper$runBody$1.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:128)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.downlevel(CompilerPhase.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper.runBody(CompilerPhase.kt:127)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanDriverKt.runTopLevelPhases(KonanDriver.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:77)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:83)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:219)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$mainNoExit$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:246)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$mainNoExit$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:238)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.UtilKt.profileIf(Util.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.UtilKt.profile(Util.kt:21)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion.mainNoExit(K2Native.kt:245)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2NativeKt.mainNoExit(K2Native.kt:376)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt$daemonMain$1.invoke(main.kt:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt$daemonMain$1.invoke(main.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.mainImpl(main.kt:17)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.daemonMain(main.kt:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.KonanCliRunner.run(KotlinNativeToolRunner.kt:206)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinNativeCompile.compile(KotlinNativeTasks.kt:278)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinNativeLink.compile(KotlinNativeTasks.kt:643)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:727)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:694)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:553)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:536)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:276)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:265)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:192)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No coordinates found for DeclarationId(id=4)
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
include ':shared'
project(':shared').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../../shared')
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        //DB
        classpath 'com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:1.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url  'https://dl.bintray.com/badoo/maven' }
    }
}
```

Gradle

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip`

I tried to build a clean project before as per playground tutorial it worked fine

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-40895

Comment: I don't know what the issue is, but sqldelight on iOS will for sure have an issue if you're not using the multithreaded version of native coroutines and you are using the sqldelight coroutines extensions. For example: https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPKit/blob/8923925539870a5953ae06d0ac4113cadc991ed6/shared/build.gradle.kts#L102. I'd also personally stay on gradle 5.6.x for Kotlin 1.3.72. If you do that, add `enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA")` to settings.gradle

Comment: Hi Kevin, 
I tried to downgrade version and do as in the example you shared, now I have new errors:
```
Unresolved reference: squareup
Unresolved reference: Transacter
Unresolved reference: SqlDriver
```

Comment: I'm stuck unless you have a public sample to try out.

Comment: I'm not sure what was the issue, with a new project it is gone.